# How to apply join in 3 tables if 3rd does not have primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How to join between three tables
like i have three tables
productoption, productsize and price and t3 do not have a primarykey
but the problem is that the productsize tbl do not have a primary key

productoption innerjoin productsize innerjoin price

```
select * from Prices
select * from Product
select * from ProductOption
select * from ProductSize

select PriceFor, SourceID, MainPrice 
from Prices 
where PriceFor = 2 
  and SourceID in (select ProductOptionID from ProductOption where ProductId=7)
select * from Product
select ProductID, ProductName +' - '+ Convert(varchar(5),ProductID) as C
from Product

need inner join btw productoption > productsize and productoption > price
```

Comment: by `productoption > productsize` do you mean " where productoption greater than productsize"?

Comment: Can you show your table structures?

Answer (score 5):

Well lacking a primary key does not stop you doing a join. The join can be any column you choose. The following sytax will join 3 tables

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM
   A
   INNER JOIN
   B
   INNER JOIN
   C
   ON B.Col1 = C.Col2
   ON A.Co3 = B.Col4
```

However the performance may not be good if you dont have indexes which cover the columns used in the joins. I presume your question is how to join 3 tables? Note the order of the "ON"s is nested, in to out, The order of the tables (in the ON condition) is the same order as they appear in the initial part join statement. Can be confusing

Comment: It also will return more than one row for an ID, if the table without a primary key has multiple rows with the same ID.  This is somewhat contrary to the assumptions made while doing a join with a primary key.

Comment: Yes, and it will fail if the join is on text columns of different correlations etc etc. I was trying not to be too picky and if you dont have the right vocabulary, discribing these things is often difficult for newbees.

Comment: I was not trying to be over critical!  In fact, I rather like this answer.  The intention of my earlier comment was to point out what I considered to be the other really main difference between this join and a primary key join.  Thank you for contributing!